# Extracting metadata of a file using php

Tags: php, javascript, image, video, metadata

There are many file formats nowadays(audio,video,image,text).I wish to write a php code that can get me the metadata of the file irrespective of its format.

To get the basic metadata(filename,filesize,filetype and last modified date),one may use the filesystem API:

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<output id="list"></output>

<script>
  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
    var output = [];
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
    output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ',
                 f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ',
                 f.lastModifiedDate ? f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString() : 'n/a',
                 '</li>');
    }
    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
  }
  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
```

But,I wish to extract **every damn possible thing** I can manage to extract from the file(every possible metadata).

Ex: For a jpg image,on extracting its metadata,i get(using exif tags):

```
FILE.FileName: idfo1.jpg 
FILE.FileDateTime: 1369637595 
FILE.FileSize: 126948 
FILE.FileType: 2  
FILE.MimeType: image/jpeg 
FILE.SectionsFound: ANY_TAG, IFD0, EXIF 
COMPUTED.html: width="915" height="1246" 
COMPUTED.Height: 1246 
COMPUTED.Width: 915 
COMPUTED.IsColor: 1 
COMPUTED.ByteOrderMotorola: 1 
COMPUTED.ApertureFNumber: f/2.6 
COMPUTED.UserComment:  
IFD0.ImageWidth: 2048 
IFD0.ImageLength: 1536 
IFD0.Make: SAMSUNG 
IFD0.Model: GT-S5830 
IFD0.Software: S5830DXKPD 
IFD0.DateTime: 2012:06:06 10:18:24 
IFD0.YCbCrPositioning: 1 
IFD0.Exif_IFD_Pointer: 2232 
IFD0.UndefinedTag:0xEA1C: ê 
EXIF.ExposureTime: 1/229 
EXIF.FNumber: 26/10 
EXIF.ExposureProgram: 3 
EXIF.ISOSpeedRatings: 50 
EXIF.ExifVersion: 0220 
EXIF.DateTimeOriginal: 2012:06:06 10:18:24 
EXIF.DateTimeDigitized: 2012:06:06 10:18:24    
EXIF.MaxApertureValue: 30/10 
EXIF.MeteringMode: 3 
EXIF.Flash: 0 
EXIF.FocalLength: 355/100 
EXIF.UserComment:  
EXIF.ColorSpace: 1 
EXIF.ExifImageWidth: 2048 
EXIF.ExifImageLength: 1536 
EXIF.ExposureMode: 0 
EXIF.WhiteBalance: 0 
EXIF.SceneCaptureType: 0 
EXIF.UndefinedTag:0xEA1C: ê
```

If possible,I wish to get even the geotagging data.

Similarly,for video and audio type files,I wish to get the:

- Bitrates(Audio and Video)
- Duration
- File Create Date
- Comments
- Frame Dimensions etc.

Is there any **php** or **javascript** code which can do this directly for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NO, there's no such a thing!** You have to write your own code, because there are thousands of formats of audio & video, different codecs, different compression, modes, etc. You have to write your own code for each of them.

For example, based on codec used, video AVI file may contain a lot of different meta-data - depending of codec (there are hundreds of them).

Probably you need a lot of experience and months of coding and testing but there's certainly no quick solution.

You can probably find some basic tools but nothing can find **every damn possible thing** in every file-type you may use.

If I'm wrong and you can find some library to do that, please share, but logic says that what you want doesn't exist.

Comment: Is it necessary to absolutely use php for the job? Can javascript do it completely?

Comment: That's not purpose of JavaScript. It's probably possible but don't forget that your script have to check file on local machine or to download and check it. No way it's possible online. Another problem is that it would be probably an enormous large script which means user have to download it along with your page on each request to the server. That may cause some serious issues. In theory it's possible but in real-life you probably don't want that kind of headache - in short, it's never-ending job.

Comment: I'm curious, why you need all that info? Try to update your question with more relevant description and usage of code you need. Maybe someone may suggest something you can work with to solve your problem.

Comment: thanks!...actually i'm building a web api that analyses data adn extracts its metadata,as in future,metadata is going to take over like anything.

Comment: Whatever you do, don't use JavaScript in that purpose... you need server-side scripting language, such as PHP to do job as quick as possible. JavaScript is just client-side help to make better and more user-friendly interface (and may be disabled by the client).

Answer (score 2):

there is a class called getid3() for many mediatypes.
it's very simple to use and very powerfull .. u can read and write metadata to files.

there are also some javascript classes to read metadata like exif,id3 from files..

search for "reading exif data with javascript"
or "JavaScript ID3 Reader"

if u have your own server you can also use some commandline tools(that u execute from php) that can read exif,id3 tags and also the new mp4 tags like atomicparsley

here is a list of things u can do with getid3 and php

```
Tag formats:
ID3v1 (v1.0 & v1.1)
ID3v2 (v2.2, v2.3 & v2.4)
APE tags (v1 & v2)
(Ogg) VorbisComment
Lyrics3 (v1 & v2)
IDivX
Lossy Audio-only formats:
MP3, MP2, MP1 (MPEG-1, layer III/II/I audio, including Fraunhofer, Xing and LAME VBR/CBR headers)
Ogg Vorbis
Musepack (versions SV4-SV8)
AAC & MP4
AC-3
DTS (including DTS-in-WAV)
RealAudio
VQF
Speex
Digital Speech Standard (DSS)
Audible Audiobooks
Lossless Audio-only formats:
WAV (including extended chunks such as BWF and CART)
AIFF
Monkey's Audio
FLAC & OggFLAC
LA (Lossless Audio)
OptimFROG
WavPack
TTA
LPAC (Lossless Predictive Audio Compressor)
Bonk
LiteWave
Shorten
RKAU
Apple Lossless Audio Codec
RealAudio Lossless
CD-audio (*.cda)
NeXT/Sun .au
Creative .voc
AVR (Audio Visual Research)
MIDI
Audio-Video formats:
AVI
Matroska (WebM)
ASF (ASF, Windows Media Audio (WMA), Windows Media Video (WMV))
MPEG-1 & MPEG-2
Quicktime (including MP4)
RealVideo
NSV (Nullsoft Streaming Video)
Graphic formats:
JPEG
PNG
GIF
BMP (Windows & OS/2)
TIFF
SWF (Flash)
PhotoCD
Data formats:
ZIP
TAR
GZIP
ISO 9660 (CD-ROM image)
CUEsheets (.cue)
SZIP
Metadata types:
EXIF (Exchangeable image file format)
IPTC
XMP (Adobe Extensible Metadata Platform)
Formats identified, but not parsed:
PDF
RAR
MS Office (.doc, .xls, etc)
```

Comment: Is it necessary to absolutely use php for the job? Can javascript do it completely?

Comment: search for "reading exif data with javascript" or "JavaScript ID3 Reader" javascript is clientside script ..so it's not easy to read big files... but u can do very nice simple things with this javascript classes ... i used for my digital reflex to get iso,aperture,focallength and other important info from my camera.. i think u can also get geolocation. with the mp3 class u can read most info including the cover.

Comment: its not stable like php (using a php class) or directly executed from server (with php) with commandline. In my opinion the best thing is to use commandline tools and save the info u gather into mysql db or json file once u upload the file.